# BadRequestObjectResult(Errors.AddErrorsToModelState(result, ModelState)) is not working

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I am using a code from "https://fullstackmark.com/post/13/jwt-authentication-with-aspnet-core-2-web-api-angular-5-net-core-identity-and-facebook-login" but I can't get past the AccountsController since I get this error: "The name 'Errors' does not exist in the current context"

This is my code:

```
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using AutoMapper;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using webapi.DataContext;
using webapi.Models;
using webapi.ViewModels;

namespace webapi.Controllers
{
    [Route("api/controller")]
    [ApiController]
    public class AccountsController : ControllerBase
    {
        private readonly UserManager<AppUser> _userManager;
        private readonly IMapper _maper;
        private readonly ApplicationDbContext _appDbContext;
        public AccountsController(UserManager<AppUser> userManager, IMapper maper, ApplicationDbContext appDbContext)
        {
            _appDbContext = appDbContext;
            _maper = maper;
            _userManager = userManager;

        }

        [HttpPost]
        public async Task<IActionResult> Post(RegistrationViewModel model) 
        {
            if(!ModelState.IsValid){
                return BadRequest(ModelState);
            }

            var userIdentity = _maper.Map<AppUser>(model);

            var result = await _userManager.CreateAsync(userIdentity, model.Password);

            if (!result.Succeeded) return new BadRequestObjectResult(Errors.AddErrorsToModelState(result, ModelState));

            await _appDbContext.Customers.AddAsync(new Customer { IdentityId = userIdentity.Id, Location = model.Location });
            await _appDbContext.SaveChangesAsync();

            return new OkObjectResult("Account created");
        }
    }
}
```

I get the error on this line:

> if (!result.Succeeded) return new BadRequestObjectResult(Errors.AddErrorsToModelState(result, ModelState));

[image]

Can you please show me how to this right? Than you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `Errors` is no more than [a plain custom helper class](https://github.com/mmacneil/AngularASPNETCore2WebApiAuth/blob/43ee286acaf745f11b2e06a10248e2d00a169896/src/Helpers/Errors.cs#L8-L26).

To fix your issue, simply add a class as below:

```
    public static class Errors
    {
        public static ModelStateDictionary AddErrorsToModelState(IdentityResult identityResult, ModelStateDictionary modelState)
        {
            foreach (var e in identityResult.Errors)
            {
                modelState.TryAddModelError(e.Code, e.Description);
            }

            return modelState;
        }

        public static ModelStateDictionary AddErrorToModelState(string code, string description, ModelStateDictionary modelState)
        {
            modelState.TryAddModelError(code, description);
            return modelState;
        }
    }
```